# How to implement 'Starts with' search in elasticsearch 2.x

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement where I need to return only those records whose comments donot start with a String. PFB the query and this approach is not working. Need help

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "fields": ["id","comment"], 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "comment":
              "AG//*"
          }

        }
      ]
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your mapping? is comment field not_analyzed ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should remove the `"size": 0` from your query (or set the required size) to see the results.

Now, the best way to implement '**Starts with**' in elasticsearch is by using the [Prefix Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) as follows:

```
{
   "fields": ["id", "comment"],
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must_not": [
            {
               "prefix": {
                  "comment": "AG"    <-- No need for any wildcards
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

**Note:** The Prefix Query and Wildcard Query makes sense only on **not_analyzed** fields, so make sure your `"comment"` field has the same mapping.